# Javascript: Не работает деструктуризация объекта, когда ключ String

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Пример кода.

---

Такой вариант работает:

```
const user1 = { email: "vasya@yandex.ru", name: "Vasya" };
const { email, name} = user1;
```

Такой вариант не работает:

```
const user2 = { "email": "vania@yandex.ru", "name" : "Vania" };
const { email, name} = user2;
```

Такой вариант тоже не работает:

```
const user3 = { "email": "vania@yandex.ru", "name" : "Vania" };
const { "email" : email , "name" : name} = user3;
```

Eсли формат ключа `""` то value равно `undefined`.

---

Как вытащий значение по ключу из объекта в таком случае?

---

**EDIT...**

Всем спасибо, нашел в чем проблема была. Я забыл запарсить response из string в object. Тем самым пытался четно диструктить стринг)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё прекрасно работает не зависимо от `""` Вы пытаетесь вытащить `email2` хотя данного ключа в объекте у Вас по просту нет! исправьте на `email` и т.д.

```js
const user2 = { "email": "vania@yandex.ru", "name" : "Vania" };
const { email, name} = user2;

console.log(email);
```

Comment: Спасибо, я допустил опечатку когда писал пример кода. Но все равно такой вариант не работает для меня. Хоть он и работает в Вашем примере.

Comment: Спасибо я нашел в чем проблема. напишу сейчас edit выше...

Comment: @Qui-GonJinn рад помочь))